# Terminal does not work in the WebStorm 9

Tags: webstorm

I can not type in the terminal:

[image]

What is the problem? Help please.

Comment: what is your Windows version? I can suggest creating a support ticket. Please make sure to attach your idea.log to it

Comment: See the fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153076/webstorm-phpstorm-issue-with-terminal-on-windows-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. **Disabling** "experimental features" for `cmd` did the trick for me. Right click the title bar of the cmd and go properties.

Be sure to **restart** Webstorm or PhpStorm after doing these.

For Windows 10:
Just check the "Use legacy console" option.

[image]

For Windows 10 Technical Preview: Uncheck "Enable Experimental Console features" in "Experimental" tab
[image: disable experimental features of cmd.exe]

Answer (score 7):

I have Windows 10. I went to CMD properties and enabled the "use inherited console" option.  (Sorry, my print is in Portuguese. But I think it will help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding new terminal tab (open new session) by pressing the green PLUS sign (or right click->new session). 
This worked for me.