# WebStorm/PhpStorm, issue with terminal on Windows 10

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, windows-10

I decided to try Windows 10, but having problem to make terminal works inside WebStorm/PhpStorm.

When I open terminal, sometimes it's completely black, sometimes it loads the project folder but I cannot type there. There is a way to run it in the external window, but I just got accustomed to work with console like internal window inside WebStorm/PhpStorm...

I tried cmd, Power Shell - same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Workaround:** Terminal works fine in Windows 10 if you use **legacy console**.

To do so, open a command prompt window, right click on the title, then select Properties. At the bottom, check "Use legacy console". Confirm the dialog window and go back to WebStorm to launch a new terminal. It should work.

---

**In any case**, this is the ticket to watch after:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143300 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

**UPDATE:**
This issue has now been resolved -- the fix will arrive in next major version -- PhpStorm v10/WebStorm v11 (or whatever that version will be as long as it's based on 142.xx branch or newer).

---

**UPDATE:**
For those who have problems with right clicking and finding "Properties" menu entry:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank  you, sir!!! It bothered me so much that I was going to come back to Windows 8, you saved me 3 hours.

Comment: fantastic! That was driving me insane

Comment: Vote up because its works, but its ridiculous that I have to reconfigure my OS to use PHPStorm, this bug should have been fixed by the creators before Windows 10 release!

Comment: I cannot find the properties setting when I right click on the Terminal title at the top of bottom of the popup terminal. I am getting things like Show Toolbar, floating mode, docked mode, pinned mode, etc but nothing that says properties. Any ideas?

Comment: @WallyKolcz This should be performed in Windows 10 Terminal and NOT PhpStorm/WebStorm/another-JB-IDE. http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/enable-use-legacy-console-for-command-prompt-in-windows-10.html

Comment: @LazyOne that issue on youtrack appears to be resolved, so it won't allow more votes. thx for the fix!

Comment: @LazyOne The time you took, coming back and editing, is to be applauded, sir. I said, good day.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: I have [confirmation](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18292) from JetBrains that it will be fixed (i.e. work with non-legacy mode) in WebStorm 11 which is scheduled for the beginning of November. In the EAP version it should already work.

Comment: Thank you, PzYon. It's already working but it's nice to have it officially fixed. 
P.S. Honestly, developer should be flexible for any changes, but this issue was very annoying for me and 1 week with External Power shell made me very said but a good guy LazyOne showed in the right time and saved all of us - HAPPY END!