# PhpStorm 2021.1.3 terminal is not functional on Windows 10

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

Newest **PhpStorm terminal** is not functional on Windows 10. Using legacy console setting for CMD does not help to solve the issue. Cannot type anything inside terminal.

Meaning this old 2015 year fix: [WebStorm/PhpStorm, issue with terminal on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153076/webstorm-phpstorm-issue-with-terminal-on-windows-10)

does not solve the issue.

This issue happens on a specific Dell laptop only. Meaning it's not common on other computers I've tried to install it. Maybe could be related to some BIOS setting?

Comment: Please, provide a bit more details: what shell path is specified under *File | Settings | Tools | Terminal*? Do you see any errors in the logs (_Help | Show log in Explorer_?)

Comment: I've just looked into very similar problem that was caused by unicode characters in a user profile name. So yes, as advised above, we would need to look into IDE logs first of all.

Comment: Dmiitrii, yes, correct actually it was because of the Lithuanian letters of the user account folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened because of the Lithuanian letters of the user folder in the system which came from Microsoft account of the computer.